# How to have multiple columns in a list

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented a **phone gap** application using **Sencha Touch,**

**`I Want to add 4 columns in a list`** it self as shown bellow

[image].

*For now i used 4 different lists with 25% width...,*

But **i need to display 4 columns in each row, with in a single list.**

And more over Here i mentioned Headers also as data, But **how sh'd we mentioned header in a separate header for each column.**

My code its working for display but invalid :

```
   extend: 'Ext.Panel',

   config: {
   layout: {
   type: 'vbox'
   },
   items: [
           {
           xtype: 'toolbar',
           docked: 'top',
           title: 'Color Fields',

           },
                {
           xtype: 'list',
           height: 243,
           margin: '',
           left: 0,
           ui: '',
           width: '20%',

           itemTpl: [
                     '<div><b>{Cloumn1}<b></div>'
                     ],


           data: [
                  {Cloumn1: 'SerialNum' },
                  {Cloumn1: '1'},
                  {Cloumn1: '1'},
                  {Cloumn1: '2'}
                  ]
           },
           {
           xtype: 'list',
           height: 243,
           margin: '',
           left: '25%',
           top: 0,
           ui: '',
           width: '20%',

           itemTpl: [
                     '<div><b>{Cloumn2}<b></div>'
                     ],


           data: [
                  {Cloumn2: 'Color' },
                  {Cloumn2: 'Red'},
                  {Cloumn2: 'Blue'},
                  {Cloumn2: 'White'}
                  ]

           },
           {
           xtype: 'list',
           height: 243,
           margin: '',
           left: '50%',
           top: 0,
           ui: '',
           width: '20%',

           itemTpl: [
                     '<div><b>{Cloumn3}<b></div>'
                     ],


           data: [
                  {Cloumn3: 'Box Type' },
                  {Cloumn3: 'Rectangle'},
                  {Cloumn3: 'Trianger'},
                  {Cloumn3: 'Circle'}
                  ]
           },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grid extension from Mitchell Simoens. Here is the [link](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid)

Answer (score 1):

```
xtype:'list',
itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<div width = "100%">',
        '<div align="center" style="display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;width: 25%;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:25%; vertical-align:top;">{column1}</div>',
        '<div align="center" style="display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;width: 25%;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:25%; vertical-align:top;">{column2}</div>',
        '<div align="center" style="display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;width: 25%;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:25%; vertical-align:top;">{column3}</div>',
        '<div align="center" style="display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;width: 25%;word-wrap:break-word;max-width:25%; vertical-align:top;">{column4}</div>',
    '</div>'
),
```